# Export Query Result as CSV file from Docker PostgreSQL container to local machine

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, csv, psql

I'm not sure if this is possible of if I'm doing something wrong since I'm still pretty new to Docker. Basically, I want to export a query result inside PostgreSQL docker container as a csv file to my local machine.

This is where I got so far. Firstly, I run my PostgreSQL docker container with this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=something -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

Then I access the docker container with docker exec to run PostgreSQL command that would copy the query result to a csv file with specified location like this:

```
\copy (select id,value from test) to 'test_1.csv' with csv;
```

I thought that should export the query result as a csv file named test_1.csv in the local machine, but I couldn't find the file anywhere in my local machine, also checked both of these directories: `$HOME/docker/volumes/postgres`; `/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres`

Comment: The file will be inside the container, perhaps in the root directory.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's nowhere to be found. Also, I'm only running a PostgreSQL docker container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can export the data to the `STDOUT` and pipe the result to a file in the client machine:

```
docker exec -it -u database_user_name container_name \
psql -d database_name -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO STDOUT CSV" > output.csv
```

`-c`  tells psql you to execute a given SQL statement when the connection is established.

So your command should look like this:

```
docker exec -it -u postgres pgdocker \
psql -d yourdb -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM test) TO STDOUT CSV" > test_1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Jim for your answer! When I run this command, I got this error and not sure what it means or how to fix it: `psql: error: missing "=" after "COPY" in connection info string`

Comment: @nhtnhan can you try this? `docker exec -it -u your_user postgresql14 psql -d your_db -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM your_table) TO STDOUT CSV"`

Comment: if you want to export with headers, change this: 
` "COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER" `

Answer (score 0):

The `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory is where the database server stores its data files. It isn't a directory that users need to manipulate directly or where nothing interesting can be found.

Paths like `test_1.csv` are relative to working directory. The default directory when you enter the postgres container with `docker exec` is `/` so that's where your file should be. You can also switch to another directory with `cd` before running `psql`:

```sh
root@b9e5a0572207:/some/other/path# cd /some/other/path/
root@b9e5a0572207:/some/other/path# psql -U postgres
```

... or you can provide an absolute path:

```
\copy (select id,value from test) to '/some/other/path/test_1.csv' with csv;
```

You can use `docker cp` to transfer a file from the container to the host:

```
docker cp pg-docker:/some/other/path/test_1.csv /tmp
```

... or you can create a volume if this is something you do often.