# Not able to export csv file in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am a beginner in PostgreSQL. I have connected to postgres using

> sudo -u postgres psql

Then I connected to 'test' database as 'postgres' user using the following command:

> postgres=# \c test

Now when I try to export the results to home directory using the following command;

> test=# \copy (select * from person left join car on
> person.car_id=car.id) to '/home/navdeep/Downloads/data.csv' delimiter
> ',' csv header;

I get the following error;

> /home/navdeep/Downloads/data.csv: Permission denied

What could be the reason. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Just change location of file that you had permission. https://www.neilwithdata.com/copy-permission-denied

Comment: Does it help the question if you tag four old, unsupported PostgreSQL versions? Instead, how about checking the permissions on the directory and all directories above that?

Comment: Since you're using psql, the easiest way would be pipe the result set to `stdout`, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/69709009/2275388 doing so you don't have to worry about permissions for the `postgres` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try saving to the temp folder? I don't think you'll have any permission issues there.